# How to create a new function parameter dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

I have a chat bot, that shows every function parameter, so the user can change it and then get the function result in chat.

Let's say I have a function:

```
def func(a=0, b=0):
    return a+b

func(*user_settings)
```

But I want it to be able to recognize the user. I can't just add a 'user' parameter because it will be shown in chat.
Can I add a parameter to the function dynamically, so it becomes smth like:

```
def func(a=0, b=0):
    print(func.user)
    return a+b

(add 'user' parameter)
func(*user_settings)
```

Function is an object, right?
I think that just hardcode not to show a specific parameter is too dumb.
p.s. the function is also decorated.

Comment: Yes, you can add `func.user`, but this would be equivalent to variables with static lifetime.

Comment: @ThomasLang + thank you!

Comment: Function attributes aren't commonly used; typically, you would create a class whose instances have a `user` attribute, and `func` would be a method of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func.user=user
```

works for me, thanks for @ThomasLang